# Customize Windows 10 Start Menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-desktop, startmenu

I have a potential requirement of modifying the Windows 10 Start Menu structure. I know that you can customize the groups and tiles: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2016/03/07/windows-10-start-layout-customization/

My question is if there is any possible way (through API or any other option) that allows to, instead of only pinning windows desktop applications, display your custom code.

Example: we have a group called My work which pins windows applications, but we also have a group called Discover which displays custom code, not windows 10 apps.

[image]

I think it is not achievable, but want to give it a try and ask the community. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Read Raymond Chen's blogs. This probably isn't possible, because then software manufacturers are going to create groups like _"Our awesome apps!"_ and pin them to the top.

Comment: Thank you @codecaster, will review Raymond Chen's blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify start menu should not be a feature of common UWP development. The start menu should only be controlled by customer themselves. So it's not possible for you to think about develop this kind of feature.

And as you've already see that OEM can modify OEM group. Actually you can find related info from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/customize-start-layout#oem-groups-in-the-start-menu).